# Find the points satisfying $f(x)=\sin(5x)-15$

Tags: real-analysis

Verify that $f(x)=\sin(5x)-15$ satisifes all the conditions of Rolle's theorem in the interval $[0,\pi]$. Find the points satisying the theorem.

So I  have proved that $f(x)$ satisfies the theorem and then:

$f'(c)=5\cos5c=0$

$$\cos5c=0$$

$$5c=\cos^{-1}(0)$$

$$5c=\pi/2,3\pi/2,5\pi/2,7\pi/2,9\pi/2$$

so $$c=\pi/10,3\pi/10,5\pi/10,7\pi/10,9\pi/10$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes! Actually, there are many more values for c! $c = n + \frac{\pi}{2}, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, but in $[0, \pi]$ it's what you wrote!

Comment: Your proposed solution is correct.